# Passing Scoped Model as Function Argument vs Using ScopedModelDescendant

Tags: flutter, dart, scoped-model, flutter-scoped-model

What is the recomended way to use ScopedModel in functions? Should i pass the model as an argument or should i always use ScopedModelDescendant wherever i used the model?

Using ScopedModelDescendant:

```
class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget _buildItemThatNeedsModel() {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<MyModel>(builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, model) {
      return Text(model.someDataFromModel);
    },);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildItemThatNeedsModel();
  }
}
```

Passing model as argument:

```
class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget _buildItemThatNeedsModel(MyModel model) {
    return Text(model.someDataFromModel);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<MyModel>(builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child, model) {
      _buildItemThatNeedsModel(model);
    },);
  }
}
```

It seems to me that both of them gets the job done. If i have multiple functions that uses ScopedModel, then passing models as arguments seems like better way to do.

Which one should i use?